# Mixing PHP frameworks

Tags: symfony, kohana, boonex-dolphin

Is it possible to mix frameworks?

I want to develop a site using Symfony but have been advised to use Kohana (with Boonex Dolphin) as it is the best for plugging in social networking modules

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Not a good idea. Stick with one... There are many many Symfony2 bundles, for sure will find something that fits your needs. Or if it doesn't it can always be forked and be modified.

Comment: terrible idea, you will spend much more time integrating the libraries than actually developing the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to mix Symfony Standard Edition with any other framework. It is not recommended, but it is possible. The most common situations when you need to do this is when you migrate your old code to Symfony and when you want a blogging system to handle the blogging part of your website (like having your website on Symfony and your blog on WordPress).

To achieve that there are many ways. One is to setup in Symfony a route that will work with the legacy code. Another one is to build an adapter over your non-Symfony application (or your Symfony app).

Comment: Thanks for explaining - that makes sense. I will recommend that everyone sticks with Symfony in that case.....or is Kohana/Boonex Dolphin a worthwhile alternative to consider? I just don't want to get in a mess with a new framework further down the road....!

Comment: Kohana and Boonex Dolphin have architectures totally different than the one of Symfony. Also they are not supporting namespaces, so from a developer point of view I will totally choose Symfony. Also Symfony is a more mature framework and you will find bundles for almost every need of yours.